# Limitations of OpenCV regarding its depth?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, colors, rgb

Does OpenCV deals with data which occupies:

- 8 bits?
- 12 bits?
- 16 bits?

According to what I have combined, for a 3Channel IplImage, using unsigned bit, it can only deals with 24 bits and 48 bits.

Please correct me if my conclusion regarding the limitation of openCV is correct!

Comment: you should *not* use IplImage anymore, but cv::Mat

Answer (score 1):

in newer OCV versions the cv::Mat is used as image container.

you may look at the type parameter of the mat-c'tor

it takes a constant build the following way:

> type: Type of the matrix elements. 
>   Specified in form CV_<bit_depth>(S|U|F)C<number_of_channels>.
>   E.g.: CV_8UC1 means an 8-bit unsigned single-channel matrix, 
>   CV_32SC2 means a 32-bit signed  matrix with two channels.

But supported by image data type and supported by image processing algorithms are two different points.
The most algorithms only work on 8bit or floating point single channel images.